# Rotating Header and Caption of Imported PDF using pdfpages

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages, pdflscape

I want the PDF to be landscape, but the caption and the header to be as they would be in portrait mode. Attached is an image of the current output that I have from the code. In addition, I have added in the current code that I am using.[image: Current Output]

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
oneside,
english,
singlespacing]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{thesis}
\chapter{Schematics}
\begin{landscape}
    \includepdf[pages=-, landscape=true, pagecommand={\pagestyle{thesis}}, picturecommand*={\put (\LenToUnit{.1\paperwidth},18) {CAD Presentation of Design with Labels};}]{Appendices/Watch_Lid.pdf}
% \includepdf[pages=-,linktodoc=true, landscape, picturecommand*={\put (\LenToUnit{.05\paperwidth},20) {Page 3 in the original.};}]{Appendices/Watch_Face.pdf}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pdfpages changes the *orientation* of the page when using option `landscape`. But it does not and can not change the *page layout*, because it highly depends on the used LaTeX class how to change the page layout. (And it is not without controversy that rotating header/footer is correct. It might be comfortable on a slide or some other online document, but it might look peculiar in a book.)

Since I do not know your LaTeX class `MastersDoctoralThesis`, I will take `scrreport` from KomaScript to show how to change the page layout.

```
\documentclass[areasetadvanced,DIV=12]{scrreport}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\cohead{testing}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait, DIV=current}
\lipsum[1-6]

\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}
\includepdf[
  scale=0.7,
  pagecommand={},
  picturecommand*={\put(150,70){some test}}
]{example-image.pdf}
\lipsum[1-6]

\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,DIV=current}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```